# How to change the default drag und drop behavior in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook

In order to archive E-Mails within Outlook 2010, I have to copy them into a special windows 7 folder.

In general I mark the E-Mails within Outlook and copy paste them into the folder.

The Problem:
For a better overview I would like to have an automatic process which adds the creation date of the E-Mail at the beginning of the file name.

Instead of having xxx.msg in the folder, I would like to have 20161125-xxx.msg

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: What special folder are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with a simple drag and drop.

Your options would probably to:

- Copy the mails into a temporary folder, run a script to rename them and copy them to the final location
- Write some extension for Outlook using VBA which helps you to automate this
- Create a second data file in that special folder and just move/copy the emails to the second data file using a outlook rule.

The last method might not be a solution for you if you need those mails as `.msg` files.